# datepicker appears behind the modal

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

Date picker appears behind the modal box how to make it appear above the modal box.  As the date picker appears behind the modal form and I am unable to access it.

```
$('#modal_div_res').html("
    <div><input class='form-control datepicker_input' type='date' id='date' name='date'>
    </div>
");
```

Comment: i bet it is a css issue... inspect the css. and post here all the relevant code

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too. Just put this AFTER the bootstrap css.

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
z-index: 10000 !important;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Giving your date picker a z-index higher than that of you modal box will cause it to display over the top of the modal.

```
    modal style='z-index:8'

    datepicker style='z-index:9'
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix same problem by this :

```html
<style>
 .datepicker-plot-area {
  z-index: 1151 !important;
 }
    </style>
```